# Compile Socat for Android

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

I am trying to compile Socat for Android. I have downloaded the source code and when attempting to run `./socat_buildscript_for_android.sh` I get the following:

```
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 19: /root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/prebuilt-common.sh: No such file or directory
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 29: register_var_option: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 34: register_option: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 37: register_var_option: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 40: register_var_option: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 44: register_var_option: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 47: register_var_option: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 50: register_var_option: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 53: register_var_option: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 56: register_var_option: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 59: register_option: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 72: register_option: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 74: extract_parameters: command not found
Auto-config: --arch=arm
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 156: run: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 158: fail_panic: command not found
/root/bin/android-ndk-r23/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh: line 163: dump: command not found
```

I downloaded NDK and updated the path in the `socat_buildscript_for_android.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Since Android's ndk-19 has provided compiler toolchain in path: ndk-X/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$HOST_TAG/bin/...
You don't need make_standalone_toolchain.
Refer to more details: [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems)

Comment: How can I compile this then?

Comment: - You can comment make_standalone command
- Next, update the compiler (arm, arm64 or armv7a) in the CC variable (at ./configure command)
Example:
CC="yourNDKpath/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang".  (all edited in file: socat_buildscript_for_android.sh)

Comment: Looks like something was going on. Then it failed due to to many errors.

Comment: I tried a few different build scripts (arm7a, i686, etc) and they all end up failing due to to many errors emmited. Errors in the actual c code.